# Make Shrine gem to reprocess attachment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, shrine

I have an uploader, with some generated versions

```
class ImageUploader < Shrine
  ...
  process(:store) do |io, context|
    versions = { original: io }
    # some additional versions
  end
  ...
end
```

I have some "broken" records, that has this file in unpromoted state. That happens because backgrounding job throws error in promoting process. So, these records stuck in "cached" state.

```
post.image_attacher.stored? # => false
post.image_attacher.cached? # => true
```

How can I force them to regenerate versions? I tried from docs like:

```
post.update image: post.image
```

It does not work. This does not trigger processing logic at all. How can I force run storing process with generating all versions?

Comment: You should be able to just respawn the background job with the same arguments. If you're not able to do that, I think running `post.image_attacher._promote(action: :store)` should work.